# ValueInjecter ViewModel to EF poco

Tags: c#, valueinjecter

I have the following ViewModel:

```
public class MessageViewModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Contact")]
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

I use ValueInjecter for mapping:

```
 MessageViewModel = new MessageViewModel{ ContactID = 42 };
 Message msg = new Message();
 msg.InjectFrom<UnflatLoopValueInjection>(viewModel);
```

But ValueInjecter sets msg.ContactID and msg.Contact.ID. How can I avoid it?

Comment: Show us the Contact class.  Are you saying it's trying to map to model.Contact.ID, and you don't want it to?  Which ID do you want it to map to?

Comment: I added the Contact class. I try to map to model.ContactID only.

Comment: Why do you need the Model class?  All it is doing is creating an unnecessary layer of abstraction, and it's complicating things by requiring you to maintain two ID's, not just one.

Comment: I edited the example. The ContactID is the foreign key for Contact. In the View I have a DropDown wich returns the ID value.

Comment: to avoid msg.ContactID to msg.Contact.ID have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27444756/112100

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
msg.InjectFrom<FlatLoopValueInjection>(viewModel);
```

What you are getting is the expected behavior.

[flattening](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=flattening&referringTitle=Home), [unflattening](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=unflattening&referringTitle=Home)

Comment: I think unflattening is the right convention. I only want to avoid the mapping of foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to map only to model.Text and model.ContactID do this:

```
msg.InjectFrom(viewModel);
```

Contact.ID was being populated because you were using Unflattening so from source.ContactID it was going to target.Contact.ID

to avoid this (ignore certain properties) have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27444756/112100

Comment: I need unflattening. But for Entity Framework code first I only need the ContactID and not an empty Contact object.